# How to structure Typescript library code to generate d.ts file that can be used by Typescript app?

Tags: typescript

I’m building a Typescript library (bundled into a single .js file) and a Typescript client app that uses the library’s bundled .js file and d.ts file

- I’d like to use TS modules instead of TS namespaces, unless these goals make that impossible
- Within the library’s code, I’d like to refer to library objects in
  other files directly; e.g. "new Label(...)"
- In the app that is using the library, I’d like be able to refer to library objects with nesting and from within a single namespace; e.g. "new
  lib.Controls.Label()"
- I’d like the d.ts file to be automatically generated

I've created a sample VSCode project with the below code at https://github.com/jeffsim/soExportImportIssue.  You can download it, npm install, and build to see the issue.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// ... LibraryProject/Controls/Control.ts
export default class Control {
    constructor() {
    }
}

// ... LibraryProject/Controls/Label.ts
import Control from "./Control"
export default class Label extends Control {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

// ... LibraryProject/Library.ts
export default class Library {
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

The project linked above also has a custom build environment (covered in [this](https://github.com/jeffsim/typescriptGulpSample/) github repo), but I don’t think it’s relevant to this question.

The Library code compiles w/o issue, and it generates the following d.ts file:

```
declare module "Library" {
    export default class Library {
        constructor();
    }
}
declare module "Controls/Control" {
    export default class Control {
        constructor();
    }
}
declare module "Controls/Label" {
    import Control from "Controls/Control";
    export default class Label extends Control {
        constructor(label: String);
    }
}
```

I’m not sure if that’s the general format of the d.ts that I should want (and the ‘import’ in there makes me uncomfortable).  Even if it’s correct, I know it would still need some kind of aggregate export, but I’m not sure how to define that.  Before getting to that, here’s how I’m using the Library in the App:

AppProject\typings\libraryProject.d.ts - contains the d.ts contents described above

```
// AppProject\Test.ts
// Although the d.ts is ambiently included and so shouldn’t need to be 
// imported, as it stands above there isn’t an ‘aggregate export’ in it, so
// I may need something like this (which doesn’t work):
//   import * as lib from "./typings/libraryProject";

export class Test {
    constructor() {
        // This doesn't work as-is; not present ambiently (since 'lib' 
        // isn't in the d.ts), and 'lib' isn't explicitly imported (since 
        // I can't get import above to work)
        var v = new lib.Controls.Label("EHLO WLRD");
    }
}
```

Which leads to the Q – how can I enable that ‘lib.Controls.Label’ line to work, while allowing the Library to continue importing internally as described above?  If I manually change the d.ts file to the following, then the lib.Controls.Label line in the App works; but I can’t figure out what changes to make to the Library’s source files to get it to both generate this d.ts file and still work as described above.

```
declare module lib {
    export class Library {
        constructor();
    }
}
declare module lib.Controls {
    export class Control {
        constructor();
    }
}
declare module lib.Controls {
    export class Label extends Control {
        constructor(label: String);
    }
}
```

I *can* get the Library to output that kind of d.ts if I move to namespaces, but then I’m no longer using modules/import.  E.g., changing Controls.ts as follows generates the above d.ts format:

```
namespace lib {
    export class Control {
        constructor() {
        }
    }
}
```

Should I (1) somehow change the Library to output a different d.ts file, (2) have a post-process that somehow modifies the d.ts file (e.g. by appending some kind of aggregate export), or (3) is there a different import line in the App that would work?  Or should I just use namespaces?

Comment: One `.d.ts` file should be generated for each of your `.js` modules. In your `index.ts` file, you just need to export the things you want to be easily accessible from your library. End users will be able to do `import * as Lib from "your-library"` and then do things like `Lib.Controls`, assuming you export a `Controls` object from `index.ts`

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I do not believe that to be the solution to this problem.  I've tried a variety of 'aggregate.ts' style solutions, but all they do is add 'import' statements into the bundled d.ts, which doesn't help.  Happy to be wrong; can you provide an example index.ts which shows otherwise?

Comment: Why are you against having `import` statements in your `.d.ts` file? I would also recommend against using `outFile` in your build - you'll find things easiest if you generate one `.js` file and one `.d.ts` file for each module in your library.

Comment: The example above is intended to demonstrate a library (like jquery) and a client-side app (completely unrelated to jquery).  I want to create a single, bundled "library.js" file that the app can include via <script>, much like it includes jquery.  As far as being against imports in the .d.ts - it doesn't make sense (afaik) to do so in the scenario I just outlined.  e.g. if jquery.d.ts included "import...from 'src/event/ajax'", it would be meaningless to the app that's consuming the d.ts, right?