# Is it possible to get design/build-time errors for static properties when missing Typescript /// reference?

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript project which generates a single bundled .js library for use in client-side webapps. I am using namespaces and /// references.  I would like to get design/build-time errors when one file in the library depends on another file and there is no /// reference present; otherwise, it won’t be discovered until runtime.

With the following, I get a nice compile-time error:

```
// AClass.ts
namespace test {
    export class AClass extends ZClass {
        constructor() {
            super();
        }
    }
}
...
// ZClass.ts
namespace test {
    export class ZClass {
        constructor() {
        }
    }
}
```

TSC build complains that `error TS2690: A class must be declared after its base class` as expected, and adding `/// <reference path=’zclass.ts’` fixes it, again as expected.  This is what I’m looking for.

The problem is when you instantiate a static variable, it doesn’t seem to get caught at build time.  e.g., change the above code as follows:

```
// AClass.ts
namespace test {
    export class AClass {
        static z = new ZClass();
        constructor() {
        }
    }
}
...
// ZClass.ts
namespace test {
    export class ZClass  {
        constructor() {
        }
    }
}
```

When you compile now, no build errors are emitted; but when you run you get `"test.AClass is not a constructor"` because ZClass isn’t defined at this point in the bundled .js file; that definition occurs after AClass.  If you switch the object names, then it works.  Or, if you add `/// <reference path="ZClass.ts"/>` to AClass.ts, it works.

Is it possible for TSC to output a build error in this scenario?  My concern is that it's easy to miss adding one of those references.

Corollary: using modules&imports addresses this nicely, but I’ve run into other issues with that approach (discussed in this SO question: [How to structure Typescript library code to generate d.ts file that can be used by Typescript app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511746/how-to-structure-typescript-library-code-to-generate-d-ts-file-that-can-be-used)), so I’m exploring if namespaces can be made to work here.